# Can I use alternate Receive Buffers?

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer

In C#, Can I change the RX buffers ?

i.e., I may have data coming at me at pretty high speed; not exactly sure at this moment (no scopes or timing or anything; hope I never get to that point).

What I'm thinking (if this is possible) is to change Serial port's buffer (to an alternate one) as soon as the DataReceivedHandler takes over, and use the old buffer for data in other parts of the program.

I'm thinking I might have 3 or 4 of these buffers stacked up, which could happen once per second.

I didn't see this sort of question answered; if it does exist, please just point me to it.

Pretty new to this aspect of code, so apologies if this idea is a disaster to avoid. My data is coming at me at BlueTooth speeds and I'm honestly not sure if I'm going to have to throttle it on the other side or whatever.

Comment: Serial-port / bluetooth speeds are not very high for a modern PC. Focus on receiving your data correctly first, worry about speed when you have an actual problem.

Comment: I've done more than my share of serial port code (at speeds up to 115,200) and never had a problem keeping up with constant streaming.

Comment: This is what you normally do.  You create a new buffer and read data into it.  Until it is "complete", then you hand it over to another thread to process it.  The UI thread being a popular example.  And create a new buffer for the next chunk of data.  Creating buffers like this makes it automatically thread-safe.